# Why the error "no such file or directory" prompted when run the android NDK compiling command arm-linux-androideabi-*?

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

On my Ubuntu 16.04LTS, there is a Android NDK r8 development kit. When I run `toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`, I've gotten a error like "no such file or directory" saying there is no such file. I've tried other commands such as `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` etc.., too, but the error is still there. I've also checked those files mode to assure I have the read and executable permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.

I run

```
  file arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

which says the command is `ELF 32-bit LSB executable`. Then I get the idea about the reason.

I guess the reason is that my Ubuntu 16.04LTS is a 64bit system and has only one architecture: amd64. So I add the 32bit architecture according to [Multiarch/HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

Then I run the command `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` again, it's successfully.